# without login to paypal account accept the credit/debit cards payment

Tags: node.js, paypal

Can Paypal Express checkout integration include a payment way with credit card and debit card which do not require customer to login to paypal or to create a new paypal account?

I read lots of post here they said set SOLUTIONTYPE=sole in your SetExpressCheckout API, and also set "PayPal Account Optional" to "on" in your PayPal account -> [Profile] -> [My selling tools] -> [Website preferences].

I have on the paypal account option. But I'm not getting where to set SOLUTIONTYPE=sole in setExpressCheckout API.

I have used paypal-rest-sdk npm in my code. I have create two routes for create payment and execute paymant.

Can you please help me here

Answer (score 0):

> I read lots of post here they said set SOLUTIONTYPE=sole in your SetExpressCheckout API, and also set "PayPal Account Optional" to "on" in your PayPal account -> [Profile] -> [My selling tools] -> [Website preferences].

Those are all old classic API things that you don't need to worry about at all.

All you need to do to present a 'Debit or Credit Card' button is integrate PayPal Checkout's standard payments, as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/

For an interactive demo, see: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

---

If you will be combining this with a server backend for API calls, see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls and set up two routes that return JSON, one for "Create an order" and one for "Capture an order"

Then pair your routes with this JS for the approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Actually  I have used paypal-rest-sdk npm in my code. I have create two routes for create payment and execute payment. Is their any way in that npm that allows me to pay with credit/debit card ? –

Comment: The v1 paypal-node-sdk is deprecated. Do not use it. See above for what you should be using. It includes a black debit/credit card button.

Comment: I have used the above in my code but it shows me error.   response:
   { name: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
     message: 'No permission for the requested operation',
     information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors',
     debug_id: '2743ac05fee89',
     httpStatusCode: 403 },
  httpStatusCode: 403 }